# GIT Workflow: Merge most of a feature branch into master, omitting one specific commit?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-merge, git-revert

### The context:

Two separate features were committed onto the same branch. The oldest commit represents one cohesive feature ("Feature 1"). All the subsequent commits represent a second, separate cohesive feature ("Feature 2").

In retrospect, these should have been separate feature branches, but they were all committed to the same branch.

### The problem:

Now: The predictable problem has occurred. The dev is asked to merge Feature 2 into Master, but not Feature 1.

### What they did:

#0 they branch off MASTER, intending to use the branch for feature 2 - calling their new branch "Feature_2".

#1 they forget what branch they're on (feature 2), and make/test/commit/push a load of file changes for "Feature 1" in a single commit.

#2, 3, 4 they then go on to make all the necessary changes for Feature 2, committing and pushing, to the same branch, as they go.

Now - someone asks them to commit feature 2 (commits #2, #3, #4) without feature 1 (commit #1).

#4 they created a new branch and called it, say, "BEFORE_REVERTING_#1"

#5 They Git Revert commit#1 (Via sourcetree's 'reverse changes...' option.)

#6 they merge commit#5 into master.

Final state:

[image: Graph of final GIT history]

So now they've succeeded in merging #2,3,4 into master, without the code from #1.

### Questions:

- Now or later, how do we pull Feature 1 / Commit #1 into Master? (Such that both Features 1 and 2 are in Master, and the history is somewhat decipherable, if not entirely streamlined)

  - Am I right in saying we can't do it with just merging, because BEFORE_REVERTING_#1 is just a pointer to the same node that was later reverted, and will be fast forwarded, and need to use some other .git feature?
  - If you happne to know SourceTree UI - Is there an easy way to do this using the SourceTree?
- What should the dev have done, instead of the approach in step 4/5, assuming #1-3 had already happened?

Thank you for any help or clarification you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now or later, how do we pull Feature 1 / Commit #1 into Master?

[Cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) it. Essentially this copies the commit.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <commit id of feature 1>
```

> What should the dev have done, instead of the approach in step 4/5, assuming #1-3 had already happened?

Reverting the commit was fine. But they also could have split the feature branch into two branches.

You had this.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      1A - 2A - 2B [feature]
```

You want this.

```
      2A - 2B [feature]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      1A [feature1]
```

First, stick a new branch on 1A.

```
git branch feature1 1A

A - B [master]
     \
      1A [feature1]
        \
         2A - 2B [feature]
```

Then rebase 2A and 2B on top of master.

```
git rebase --onto master 1A 2B

      2A1 - 2B1 [feature]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      1A [feature1]
```

And you're done.

---

For a more complex untangling, use an [interactive rebase](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history) to selectively remove 
commits. For example, if you had...

```
A - B [master]
     \
      1A - 2A - 1B - 2B [feature]
```

And you wanted...

```
      2A - 2B [feature]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      1A - 1B [feature1]
```

Make a new branch at `feature`.

```
git checkout feature
git branch feature1

A - B [master]
     \
      1A - 2A - 1B - 2B [feature]
                        [feature1]
```

Then do an interactive rebase on each of them. Remove the offending commits. From `feature` remove 1A and 1B. From `feature1` remove 2A and 2B.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i master
# delete 1A and 1B

      2A - 2B [feature]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      1A - 2A - 1B - 2B [feature1]
```

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase -i master
# delete 2A and 2B

      2A - 2B [feature]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      1A - 1B [feature1]
```

Answer (score 1):

cherry-picking (per Schwern's answer) is probably the easiest solution; but do consider your team/project's branching strategy.  You may want to cherry-pick to a new `feature 1` branch and merge that into master, rather than cherry-pick directly to master.

There are various other ways to duplicate a commit that's been excluded from `master` (or some other branch) due to a revert, depending on circumstances.  If an entire branch has been excluded (because it was merged and the merge was reverted) it often makes sense to check out the branch and `rebase -f`.  The main difference is, if you do that, you will be rewriting the branch history with the new commits (unless you specifically use a procedure that doesn't); which in the case of salvaging a whole branch may be what you want, but you need to be aware of the implications of rewriting the branch if it's been shared.

Where I don't agree with the other answer is, what the dev did **might or might not** be "fine".  That depends on your team's agreements about how to use git.  This may seem nitpicky, but I get really tired of "experts" on slashdot telling teams what their working agreements should look like, just because it's how they're used to doing things.

In general the dev had two options: They could revert commits from the `feature 2` branch - they did probably the most straightforward variation of that - at the cost of having to copy the reverted commit later and having a "weird" history.  Or they could rewrite history to separate the branches, at the cost of probably causing a bit of branch clean-up for all devs since it would mean rewriting an already-shared branch's history (see the `git rebase` docs where they talk about "upstream rebase")